# How to get Nuxt 3 postinstall hooks log to stderr instead of /tmp/.../build.log in GitHub Actions?

Tags: logging, github-actions, nuxtjs3, post-install, yarn-berry

I'm currently facing build issues that **only occur in CI** and not locally. However, the logs are **hidden** and instead stored in **build.log** files under **/tmp/**

```
  ➤ YN0009: │ demo-app-297038@workspace:apps/demo-app couldn't be built successfully (exit code 127, logs can be found here: /tmp/xfs-574c9152/build.log)
```

**How can I tell Yarn / Nuxt 3 to log to stderr instead?**